# Is it possible to add if-else condition in Repository Pattern Query C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, repository-pattern

Is it possible to add if-else condition in Repository Pattern Query, if yes, then how?

I have the following query :

```
int Id=3;
IList<Demo> obj= repository.Query<Demo>(p => p.id == Id).ToList<Demo>();
```

I want the condition in the same query if Id is not equal to 0 then only

```
p => p.id == Id
```

else it should not be included in query, Is it possible?

I want something like this:

```
IList<Demo> obj= repository.Query<Demo>(Id != 0?p => p.id == Id:" ").ToList<Demo>();
```

Comment: Firstly, why do you want to do that because even if `p.id = 0` no row will be returned and if empty then also no row will returned assuming `p.id` is an identity. Why are you looking for an extra condition?

Comment: p.id is not identity actually, its a kind of statusId u can say

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<Demo> obj= repository.Query<Demo>().ToList<Demo>();

obj= Id != 0 ? obj.Where(p => p.id== Id).ToList<Demo>() : obj;
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: if `Query<Demo>()` returns IQueryable, so after to List you'll get all data without filtering. And then you filter it in "memory"

Answer (score 0):

You can move condition outside the query:

```
int Id=3;
IList<Demo> obj = repository.Query<Demo>();
if (Id != 0)
{
    obj = obj.Where(p => p.id == Id);
}
var result = obj.ToList();
```